# Firebase Automatic Sync with Local PC

Tags: mysql, database, android-studio, firebase, webserver

I'm working on a project that can take data from a Weintek HMI, put them on a webserver and then send them to an application that I created on android studio.

I've found firebase that can help me in this task.
In easybuilder that works with my hmi, I can create a mysql database that can store the data.
The problem is how can I update automatically firebase database with mysql database with an interval of time in order to access them on the android app.

If there is no solution with mysql, can someone suggest other method to extract the data and use some web server to sync it with the android app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your specific need, in terms of data volume or application, but as a workaround, maybe this can help you:

I usually apply [MQTT](https://dl.weintek.com/public/EBPro/Document/UM016005E_MQTT_UserManual_20190730_eng.pdf), which many Weintek HMIs have, to send telemetry data, and then use [NodeRed](https://nodered.org/) to process and redirect the data to a database, email, SMS, Telegram, CSV, TXT... depending on the need , which in your case could be [Firebase](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-firebase) (I never used it).

It works great for me as I don't have to worry about HMI limitations.

The problem is the reliability of the data, in terms of confirming that when the HMI sends, the server listens and writes, but there are certainly ways to deal with this, and the fact that you need to have a server with NodeRed running.

If you have never done so, in Weintek HMIs you can send the MQTT payload cyclically using macros easily.